# PHP - Get value from radio button not working

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get which button that user choose after user click the submit button.

My Code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if(isset($_POST['radio']))
{
echo "You have selected :".$_POST['radio'];  //  Displaying Selected Value
}}
```

HTML:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="search" method = "post">
            <div class="form-group">
              <span class="label label-default">Search</span>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="Amount">By Amount</label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="Quantity">By Quantity</label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="Profit">By Profit</label> 
                &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;                   
            </div>
          <button class="btn btn-default " type="submit" name="submit" value = "search"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
        </form>
```

But the php code echo nothing , it didnt get which radio button user choose. Please help, thank you

Comment: Its name is `optradio` not `radio`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a radio button's value, use the radio button's name attribute's value, so in your situation it would be:  `$_POST['optradio']`

Comment: this should be comment, not an answer

Comment: @JigarShah It's the answer to his/her question/problem

Comment: thanks, i thought i should put in the type, my mistake

Comment: @hatched Not a problem, that's why Stack overflow is here. We're here to help you, everyone can make (little) mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a non-existent `$_POST` variable name. On the server side, you should always call the `input` element name and not the `input` element type.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['optradio']))
    {
        echo "You have selected :".$_POST['optradio'];  //  Displaying Selected Value
    }
}
```